# How to split a list into two parts in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Example: `(split '(1 2 3 4) '3)`

the Answer should be: `((1 2 3) 4)`

The function required 1 list and 1 number, the output should be nested list
the nested list consist of all elements of "mylist" which are equal or less than the "num", and the greater number should be on the right of the list.

I tried but out put is only one list:

```
(define (split mylist num)
  (cond
    ((null? mylist)'())
    ((list? (car mylist))(split(car mylist) num))
    ((> (car mylist) num)(split(cdr mylist) num))
    (else(cons (car mylist) (split(cdr mylist) num)))))
```

Comment: Hi @Atif, welcome to StackOverflow. You should indent your code with four spaces to format it as code, rather than using ">".

Comment: It's not clear what the function is supposed to do, please explain it in words - for instance, the output is required to be _two_ lists or a list and a number?

Comment: it required one list and one number, the nested list have all the values which is less or equal to that number the greater number will be on the right side of the list.

Comment: @Atif - What happens in the situation where you call `(split '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)`?

Comment: @Inaimathi it should be ((1 2 3) 4 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, using built-in procedures in Racket:

```
(define (split mylist num)
  (cons
   (takef mylist (lambda (n) (<= n num)))
   (dropf mylist (lambda (n) (<= n num)))))
```

For example:

```
(split '(1 2 3 4) 3)
=> '((1 2 3) 4)

(split '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)
=> '((1 2 3) 4 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
(define (split-list xs y) 
  (define (less x)    (<= x y))
  (define (greater x) (>  x y))
  (list (filter less xs)
        (filter greater xs)))
```

An alternative:

```
(define (split-list xs y) 
  (define (less x) (<= x y))
  (define-values (as bs) (partition less xs))
  (list as bs))

(split-list '(1 2 3 4) 3)
```

Comment: and if i want it with out helper functions ?

Comment: Then you can use (lambda ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is roll your own version using named `let`. It makes one pass through the data and the result is in reverse order since it's the most effective.

```scm
(define (binary-bucket-sort lst threshold)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (less-equal '()) (greater '()))    
    (cond ((null? lst) 
           (cons less-equal greater))
          ((<= (car lst) threshold) 
           (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) less-equal) greater))
          (else 
           (loop (cdr lst) less-equal (cons (car lst) greater))))))

(binary-bucket-sort '(1 5 9 2 6 10 3 7 9 8 4 0) 5) 
; ==> ((0 4 3 2 5 1) . (8 9 7 10 6 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with some of the more functional constructs in Racket, such as `curry` and the like, you can use this rather compact approach:

```
(define (split-list xs y) 
  (call-with-values (thunk (partition (curry >= y) xs)) cons))

> (split-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) 3)
'((1 2 3) 4 5 6 7)
```