# Racket - Filter even and odd integers into two separate lists

Tags: lisp, racket

Function should take a list of integers and return a list containing two sublists -- the first containing the even numbers from the original list, the second containing the odd. My code gets the job done, but if I test it with a negative integer, such as the -5 in the second test, it just gets ignored by my code. Any ideas on how to fix?

(Side note - I know there are functions for even, odd, etc, but for this assignment I am to create them myself.)

```
(define (segregate lst)
  (list(pullEven lst)(pullOdd lst)))

(define (pullEven lst)
    (if (empty? lst)
         '()
    (if (isEven (first lst))
     (cons (first lst) (pullEven (rest lst)))
     (pullEven (rest lst)))))

(define (pullOdd lst)
    (if (empty? lst)
         '()
    (if (isOdd (first lst))
     (cons (first lst) (pullOdd (rest lst)))
     (pullOdd (rest lst)))))

(define (isEven x)
  (if (equal? (remainder x 2) 0) #t #f)
  )
(define (isOdd x)
  (if (equal? (remainder x 2) 1) #t #f)
  )

;tests
"---------------------------------------------"
"Segregate Tests"
(segregate '(7 2 3 5 8)) 
(segregate '(3 -5 8 16 99))
(segregate '())
"---------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`partition`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._partition))) function?

Comment: reminder of negative number divided by 2 is *negative* (so it's not 1;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a list into two parts in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003395/how-to-split-a-list-into-two-parts-in-scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting [`modulo`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._modulo%29%29) instead of `remainder`.

Remainder will preserve the sign of the answer (a remainder of -1 doesn't match the value of 1 that you're checking for).

Modulo returns an answer with the same sign as the denominator.

Comment: Based on @rsm's answer I added more logic to my if statement -- which worked, but switching 'remainder' to 'modulo' was the cleanest idea. Thanks everyone.